# ASP.NET Runtime error page in pages doc lib

Tags: error, configuration

In Pages document library (Publishing Portal), if we try to restore version history without document checkout, the following error is thrown "You must first check out this document before making changes." (in ULS logs).

But in the Sharepoint page, asp.net runtime error page is displayed. How to display sharepoint error page with valid message (out of box) without asp.net runtime error page.

Any configuration can solve the error page display problem?

Comment: How is it being displayed?  Does it look like an ASP.NET error page or the generic SharePoint error page?

Comment: A screenshot might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard (albeit frustrating from a UI perspective, as it's not customisable) behaviour in SharePoint. It is bad, but it's how it is. Then again, it does give an accurate description of the situation that caused the error, so it could be a whole lot worse given that it is SharePoint.